# Generating XML with an arbitrary number of nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-generation

I'm new to working with java. I'm trying to write out an XML file which has this form:

```
<option>
    <name>CompilerOptions</name>  
       <state>Directory1</state>
       <state>Directory2</state>
       <state>Directory3</state>
    </name>
</option>
```

The number of directories is arbitrary and depends on selections by the users.Here's the section of the code which should generate the XML file.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
    option.appendChild(doc.createElement("state").appendChild(doc.createTextNode(paths.get(i))));
    }
    child.appendChild(option);
```

The problem is that the output doesn't have the   tags, which I expected to be created by doc.createElement("state"). Why aren't those nodes being created?

here's an example:

```
<option>
    <name>CompilerOptions</name>
    Directory1
    Directory2
    Directory3
</option>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `option.appendChild()` and passing it the result of

```
doc.createElement(...).appendChild(...)
```

But [`appendChild()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild-org.w3c.dom.Node-) returns the newly-appended child, *not* the node it was appended to. So you're actually calling `option.appendChild()` with a text node. You want:

```
Element state = doc.createElement("state");
state.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(paths.get(i)));
option.appendChild(state);
```